# c# find controls and control reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

How do I reference controls in c# (runtime) without an ID?

For example, I have a page with one table in it.  I will be loading this page recursively using xmlhttp so I cannot refer to the table using it's id.  Is there something to the effect of `this.Page.Controls[2]`? or `Controls["Tables"][0]`?

I tried using the name `this.Controls.Find("MyTableName", true);` but need a reference to the library `System.Windows.Forms` (I think) but don't know how to add it as the `'using System.'` intellisense can't see it.

I looped through all the controls in `this.Controls` but `'system.ui.web.control' does not contain a definition for '.Name'` so I can only search for ID.

I am new to this and I am sure the solutions are infuriatingly simple.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess I don't really understand--at what part of the page lifecycle will you be make a request server side for DOM that's loaded client side?

Comment: The dataset is displayed in a tree that is much too large to load at once, so I load each node on the fly as the user expands it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To find a control on your page, it has to be a server control, like this:

```
<asp:Table runat="server">
   ...
</asp:Table>
```

Regular HTML on the page are not "controls", they are just text that gets sent to the browser. Server controls, on the other hand, are actual .NET classes which can interact with the codebehind.

You can still get a handle to this control without its ID by searching the Controls collection of its container, or by recursively searching the page. Let's start with recursively searching the Controls collection:

The Controls collection only refers to *immediate* child controls of a given control. Or immediate child controls of a Page. Those controls *in turn* have child controls of their own. It represents a tree in memory.

Here is a method to recurse down the tree from a given control and find the control by ID:

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control control, string id)
{
    Control returnControl = control.FindControl(id);
    if (returnControl == null)
    {
        foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
        {
            returnControl = child.FindControlRecursive(id);
            if (returnControl != null && returnControl.ID == id)
            {
                return returnControl;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnControl;
}
```

(Beyond the scope of this answer, this is better-done as an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)).

To find a control by something other than its ID, you can search by type:

```
if(someControl is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table)
```

Note that this is generally not a very good idea. It's not a great pattern if you end up having to search for controls this way - you should have an ID to your control, or you should have a reference to it already because it was created in code.

However, it is simple to modify the method to recursively search for a type:

```
private Control FindTable(Control startFrom)
{
    foreach(Control child in startFrom.Controls)
    {
        if(child is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Table)
        {
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            return FindTable(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could also have a generic form of this method:

```
private Control FindControl<T>(Control startFrom)
{
    foreach(Control child in startFrom.Controls)
    {
        if(child.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return child;
        }
        else
        {
            return FindControl<T>(child);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You definitely don't want to include System.Windows.Forms, as that simply includes all the code for a WinForms application. That's why Visual Studio has not included it for you in a web project - you'll never need it. System.Web.UI has everything for web controls.

Comment: I don't know why the downvote - sour grapes from the guy who deleted his answer?  So if I use your idea to search by type what argument type do define as my generic type so I can send my method other types of controls too. if(myControl is arg)?

Comment: @Praesagus I added code to demo searching by type instead of ID. I would not recommend using this method though...

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer all this.  I took your advice and restructured the code so the table is created in runtime and now have a referrence to it.  However I still have the same issue of not being able to find a control that does not have an ID should I need to in the future.

Comment: @Praesagus my point in the answer is that you should not really ever need to do that in the first place. If you run into a situation where you find yourself needing to do it, that is a sign you are going down the wrong path. Code like the kind I provided demonstrates that it is technically possible, but it is still a hack. Hacks are OK when you need to get around an ugly situation quick, but otherwise are best avoided.

Comment: in `FindControlRecursive` method you are calling it recursively like if it was an extension method: `child.FindControlRecursive(id)`, but it's not, hence the error. So either the method needs to be changed to be extension-method or to change the way you call it from inside: `FindControlRecursive(child, id)`

Comment: What if I want to reference an ID that is being using from a include file within my asp.net file?